# iOS, How to create labeled text field?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, interface-builder, uilabel

I want to create labeled text fields (UITextField, not UITextArea) as shown in the image below, either by using IB or code.
1. The label must be within the bounds of text field.
2. The label must not overlap the text being entered in the text field.
3. The text field should become first responder if its label is tapped.
Many thanks in advance.
[image: TextFields]

Comment: What is stopping you from doing it? Have you tried something?

Comment: @Alexander, The label's text gets overlapped by textfield's text -- even if the textfield is resized.

Comment: have you tried auto layout by setting required constraints

Comment: @AbbasAwan, have you even tried to add a simple `UILabel` as subview to the `UITextField` which owned by a `UIview` with border? it seems you are serious lack of imaginations here...

Comment: Use tableview cell. tableview has default this functionality

Comment: @MKR, I need to support iOS 5 so no autolayouts. holex there is no content offset for UITextField so adding label as subview even after resizing it will overlap the text and no extra touch obersvers please. Vineesh TP Thanks but its not the best solution out there.

Comment: @AbbasAwan Use AutoSizing under size inspector..

Answer (score 5):

This is doing exactly what you want, and it looks really good too:

https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField (Made by Jared Verdi)

[image]

To use it in IB simply add a normal `UITextField` to the view, than go to the `Identity Inspector` on the right pane, and change the `Custom Class` from the default `UITextField` to `JVFloatLabeledTextField`.

[image]

More implementations for the same thing:

- Rob Phillips' single and multi-line iOS version:

  https://github.com/iwasrobbed/RPFloatingPlaceholders
- Arthur A. Sabintsev's iOs implementation:

  https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/UIFloatLabelTextField

Comment: Looks very fine and just what was needed.
It requires iOS 7 though and I need to support iOS 5.
Thanks

Comment: `RPFloatingPlaceholders` is iOS6+, I think it might be a good time to let go of iOS5...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something line this.

[See this @ Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mvtextinputscroller?utm_source=Cocoa%20Controls&utm_campaign=65ad2cf3eb-Cocoa_Controls_Weekly_Roundup_2013_07_29&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_e48c477c58-65ad2cf3eb-300862421)

Below the Git repository.

[Git link](https://github.com/bizz84/MVTextInputScroller)

Comment: thanks. But I need to support iOS 5 so no autolayouts.